# Uploading image to web service leaves the image corrupt

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, afnetworking

I am trying to upload an image to a web service from an iPhone, but even though the file is successfully uploaded, the jpg cannot be viewed, it seems corrupt.

A file can be successfully uploaded and working fine using this c# code:

```
var url = http://myurl.co.uk/services/service.svc/UploadImage?id=108&ext=png;

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

using (var reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Pictures\\default.png”);
    reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
```

Yet this is the code i'm trying on iOS that leaves the file un-viewable:

Get image

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // Resize the image from the camera
    UIImage *scaledImage = [image resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:CGSizeMake(_photo.frame.size.width/2, _photo.frame.size.height/2) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
    // Crop the image to a square (yikes, fancy!)
    UIImage *croppedImage = [scaledImage croppedImage:CGRectMake((scaledImage.size.width -_photo.frame.size.width)/2, (scaledImage.size.height -_photo.frame.size.height)/2, _photo.frame.size.width, _photo.frame.size.height)];
    // Show the photo on the screen
    _photo.image = croppedImage;

    NSData *imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage,1);
    NSLog(@"Original size:%d",[imgData length]);
    NSData *smallerImage=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, 0.5);
    NSLog(@"End size:%d",[smallerImage length]);
    imageData = imgData;

    NSString *imageName = @"tempImage.jpg";
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectoryPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    NSData* settingsData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, 0.5);

    [settingsData writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Upload image:

```
-(void)uploadImageForOfferID:(NSString *)offerID imageExtention:(NSString *)extension withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))block
{
    NSString *imageName = @"tempImage.jpg";
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectoryPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];

    AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:masterURL]];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UploadImage?id=%@&ext=%@", offerID, extension];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:url parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"photo" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Complete");
        block(nil);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed");
        NSLog(@"FAILED WITH STATUS CODE %d - error description: %@", operation.response.statusCode, error.description);
        block(error);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

This method saves the image to a file first then uploads it. I also tried just uploading the data from `NSData *smallerImage=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, 0.5);` but with the same results.

Am I missing something here with the upload?

Thanks

EDIT ----

Comparing the file from simulator and the uploaded file. The simulator file is `2,538 bytes (4 KB on disk)` and the uploaded file is slightly larger at `2,698 bytes (4 KB on disk)`
The original simulator image shows a thumbnail, but the uploaded image doesn't!
The uploaded image can be opened with Photoshop, but not with Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Compare the saved image on the iDevice (even easier to do with Simulator) with what you've got on your server, it is unusual for Web Server to accept it but have corrupted data. If there is no difference just wait a while and open the image in different browser. I had a similar issue before with Chrome on Mac. Images seemed corrupt and for some cache reasons did not refresh but in Firefox looked fine.

Comment: Please see edit at bottom of question. Compared files are slightly different.

Comment: This may be irrelevant, but your c# is taking a png file and saving it to jpeg.  Is the service expecting that change?  `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Pictures\\default.png”);`  It looks like your temp image in iOS is a jpg.

Comment: I noticed that too. The c# code was supplied by the writer if the web service to show it works. The web service is setup to accept both png and jpg using the &ext=png or &ext=jpg URL field

Comment: The simulator image is `Original size:4223` yet the sent bytes by AFNetworking are `Sent 4382 of 4382 bytes`

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with you sending the image with type `image/jpeg` when the file you are pointing to in the provided code is actually a `.png` file and should be using `image/png`?

Comment: No, I have tried sending png's and jpg's with both `image/jpeg` and `image/png` but AFNetworking always seems to upload slightly more data than the image itself.