# AddBinaryField always missing bytes in UnityWebRequest Post (iOS)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, png, unitywebrequest

Unity 2019.1.9 and .12

I'm posting a `WWWForm` with several `AddField` text fields that get sent properly and also an `AddBinaryField` containing the bytes for an `EncodeToPng` image. The image arrives on the server always with missing bytes. This issue seems to only occur on iOS device and works fine in editor.

The image file bytes are saved to the iOS device photo album properly. The file size comparison for this "ground truth" image vs the one saved on server varies depending on which UnityWebRequest properties are marked explicitly as false.

- With both `.chunkedTransfer` and `.useHttpContinue` set to false, the file uploaded is only 838 bytes smaller.
- With no options like that set, 814 bytes smaller.
- With `.useHttpContinue` set to false, 778 bytes smaller.

Comment: Not sure if I should add AFNetworking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015167/uploading-image-to-web-service-leaves-the-image-corrupt

Comment: current workaround is to just use BestHTTP assset